# Can not update the data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, laravel-5

Route

```
Route::resource('/mediafile', 'MediaController');
```

MediaController

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $media = Media::findOrFail($id);
    if($request->hasFile('UserFile')) {
        $image = $request->file('UserFile');
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();  
        Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save(public_path('media/' . $filename));
        $media->MediaPath = $filename;
        $media->MediaName = $filename;
        $media->Description = $request->Description ? $request->Description : '';
        $media->save();
    }

    return response()->json($media);

}
```

View

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="media-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <label for="MediaName">Nama Media</label>
              @if($edit)
              <input type="text" id="medianame" class="form-control" name="MediaName" value="{{$mediaEdit != null ? $mediaEdit->MediaName : ''}}">
              @else
                <input type="text" id="medianame" class="form-control" name="MediaName">
              @endif
                @if ($errors->has('MediaName'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('MediaName') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <label for="Description">Description</label>
            @if($edit)
            <textarea class="form-control" name="Description" style="height: 200px">{{$mediaEdit->Description}}</textarea>
                @else
            <textarea class="form-control" name="Description" style="height: 200px"></textarea>
            @endif
                @if ($errors->has('Description'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('Description') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <label for="Gambar">Gambar</label>
            @if($edit)
            <img src="{{ asset('media/' . $mediaEdit->MediaPath) }}" style="height: 150px;margin-left: 10px">
            <textarea readonly="" class="select valid" style="height:30px; width: 100%; margin-top: 10px">{{ asset('media/' . $mediaEdit->MediaPath) }}</textarea>
                @endif
            <input type="file" name="UserFile">
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="post"></input>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

Ajax

```
$('#media-form').submit(function(){
var formData = new FormData(this);
swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?', 
  type: 'info',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Confirm!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
  },
    //function
    function(isConfirm){
      if(isConfirm){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
          type: "<?php echo $actionMethod; ?>",
          url: "<?php echo $actionURL; ?>",
          data: formData,
          dataType: 'json',
          processData: false, // Don't process the files
            contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        })
        .done(function(data){
          if(data.id){
              swal({
                title: "Saved!",
                text: "Your Category has been saved.",
                type: "success"}, function(){
                  window.location.href = "<?php echo url('mediafile'); ?>";
              });
            }else{
              swal("Try again");
            }
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data){
            swal("Cancelled", "Please fill the data first.");
            console.log('Error:', data);
        });
      } else{
        swal("Cancelled");
      }
    //end function
});
return false;
});
```

I put the MediaName, Description, and UserFile

[image]

when I clicked submit, I got data like this

[image]

I can not update the data, when I try to update them, my data have not changed.
I don't know why, I think that I did not do something wrong in my code.. Please help me to solve this if you know the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the PUT route into POST route

```
Route::resource('/mediafile', 'MediaController', ['except' => ['update']]);
Route::post('/mediafile/{id}', 'MediaController@update');
```

Because form data only can be used in method POST, so if you want to update your picture, you have to use POST method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form  name="itemGroupForm" action="{{URL::to('editItem',$items[0]->id)}}"   id="itemGroup" data-parsley-validate="" method="post"  onsubmit="return submitFormItemGroup();">

     function submitFormItemGroup() {
  var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("itemGroup"));
  form_data.append("label", "WEBUPLOAD");
  $.ajax({
      url: "{{URL::to('editItem',$items[0]->id)}}}",
      type: "POST",
      data: form_data,
      processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
      contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
  }).
```

Comment: I have tried, but doesn't work.. I have read so many question in StackOverFlow and they said that form Data only can be used in POST method, and can not be used in PUT method. Do you have any idea?